# 'import site' failed; use -v for traceback

Tags: python-3.x, remote-server

I have reviewed and tried to fix this error based on answers given to this problem, however I can't seem to solve my case.

Environment Variables:

PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib

PATH=/opt/PTK/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/name/bin

Followed by the import site failed error I get this error as well.

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
import codecs
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 95
*, _is_text_encoding=None):
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I believe something is off with my path variables. I had to point directly to site-packages because of a necessary private library.
Thoughts?

My PYTHONHOME variable is empty as of now. - One of the posted answers I found.

I have this shebang at the top of my python file.

`#!/usr/local/bin/env python3`

Comment: That traceback doesn't look complete.  You seem to have omitted a couple of lines from the end.

Comment: What command (specifically, what version of Python) are you using to run your program?

Comment: @jwodder hmmmm I'm an idiot. I was trying to do `python myfile.py` instead of `python3 myfile.py` .... just switched from windows to mac .... Thank you